# Android studio AVD emulator process terminated

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

When i try to run my virtual device i get the error:
`"The emulator process for AVD Pepper_1.9_API_23 has terminated."`
. If i take a look in the logs the important things I found where:
`"..\.android\avd\Pepper_1.9_API_23.avd\hardware-qemu.ini.lock\pid not found for Pepper_1.9_API_23"` and
`"..\.android\avd\Pepper_1.9_API_23.avd\userdata-qemu.img.lock\pid not found for Pepper_1.9_API_23".`
I have the same error with other devices and in the image you can see the files it creates. [the image of the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miO3n.png)

*The full logs*

```
2023-03-08 15:37:31,191 [1274652] SEVERE - E.9 API 23 - Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1  Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9514443
2023-03-08 15:37:31,191 [1274652] SEVERE - E.9 API 23 - JDK: 11.0.15; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2023-03-08 15:37:31,191 [1274652] SEVERE - E.9 API 23 - OS: Windows 10
2023-03-08 15:37:31,838 [1275299]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - C:\Users\kickv\.android\avd\Pepper_1.9_API_23.avd\hardware-qemu.ini.lock\pid not found for Pepper_1.9_API_23
2023-03-08 15:37:31,839 [1275300]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - C:\Users\kickv\.android\avd\Pepper_1.9_API_23.avd\userdata-qemu.img.lock\pid not found for Pepper_1.9_API_23
2023-03-08 15:37:31,839 [1275300]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pepper_1.9_API_23 is online, assuming it's not
2023-03-08 15:37:35,276 [1278737]   INFO - #c.i.i.a.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1
2023-03-08 15:37:36,588 [1280049]   INFO - #c.i.a.o.PathMacrosImpl - Saved path macros: {}
2023-03-08 15:37:36,619 [1280080]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appClingSettings took 16 ms, PluginAdvertiserExtensions took 15 ms, VcsApplicationSettings took 16 ms
2023-03-08 15:37:36,682 [1280143]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=helloHuman, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=C:\Documenten\AB School documenten\PAD\pad-1)ProjectLevelVcsManager took 16 ms, XDebuggerManager took 15 ms
2023-03-08 15:37:36,721 [1280182]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio2/jbr
```

I tried most of the things i found online and nothing seems to work